# Using Global variables to limit listbox entries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have an assignment to do. In the assignment people need to register to do a specific race.(5km 10km and 42km) the name and age of the person needs to be displayed in a listbox along with the race they are entering. However only 10 people may enter each race. The hint said to use global variables to stop more than 10 people from entering. I am stumped.

here is the question:
You are required to create an application for the  BestMed race to assist in racers to register.
The racer should type in their name, select a race type and enter their age. The racer should then
be added to a listbox.
The race types are as follows:
 5Km
 10Km
 42.5Km
The following rules apply when adding a participant to a race:
 If a racer is over the age of 65 they can only participate in the 5km race
 Each race can only have a maximum of 10 participants (Hint – Use global variable to
keep track of number of participants).

Here is the code:

```
 private void btnAddToRace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // declare variables and assign values
        string name = txtName.Text;
        string RaceType = cbxRaceType.Text;
        int age;

        // get users age
        age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);

        if(age >= 65 && cbxRaceType.Text != "5 Km") //ensure participants aged 65 only enters for 5Km
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You can only register for the 5Km race, beacuase you are 65 or older");
        }


        else
        {
            lstRace.Items.Add(name + RaceType + "Race");
        }

enter code here
```

Comment: Make some progress then post where you have problems

Comment: Simply check the number of items in ListBox and deny new record if current rows are >= 10.

Comment: I will post the code I have so far with the actual question a bit later tonight

Comment: `List<RaceDetails>` where `RaceDetails` has the person details and the distance details. Check the `Count` of the list before adding.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are always a thing to avoid. You should more have something like a config file, or if you cant have one you can use a public static class holding public static read-only or const variables.

Further more you question seems to be related to the general architecture of your program. So you should take a look at a architectural pattern called [Model–view–controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: You are right but: The difference between using static variables within normal classes and dedicated static classes for constants is that dedicated classes make your code much more readable and maintainable. Because they only contain immutable attributes and only scoop a certain domain. And later on you can easily replace them with what every logic you want like a database client or a config file reader.

Comment: I don't think `private void btnAddToRace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` is MVC.